# Storing nested objects in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to store custom codable struct with mutated property, but I'm always getting `nil` for that property.

For example, having codable struct:

```
struct Test1: Codable {
    var testDate: Date? = nil
    let name: String
    let age: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case age
    }
}
```

with the following example JSON we will decode provided struct, and assign custom property `testDate`:

```
let json = """
{
"name": "test",
"age": 30,
}
"""


let jsonData = Data(json.utf8)
var test1 = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Test1.self, from: jsonData)
test1?.testDate = Date()
```

Then we will try to store this struct in userDefaults:

```
var currentTest: Test1? {
    get {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        guard let testData = defaults.object(forKey: "test1") as? Data,
            let test = try? PropertyListDecoder().decode(Test1.self,
                                                          from: testData) else {
            return nil
        }

        return test
    }
    set {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.set(try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(newValue), forKey: "test1")
    }
}
```

While this works for all of the codable properties, when I try to access a custom property, such as `testDate` I'm getting nil:

```
currentTest?.testDate = nil
```

Is there a way to store "nested" properties without storing them as a separate instance in UserDefautls?

gist example - https://gist.github.com/ignotusverum/0cb9b57eef021eed3680530df519cedf

Comment: Btw why don't you save your json data straight to disk (write it to a json file)  instead of adding the json data to a property list? Note that UserDefaults it is not meant to store your app data. You should use it only to store your app settings. Btw when storing Data to UserDefaults it gets base64 encoded which increases its size considerably.

Comment: Btw `UserDefaults` has an specific method to retrieve data called `data(forKey)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have `CodingKeys` in Test1, you need to add `case testDate` or property testDate will be omitted when decoding instances.

```swift
struct Test1: Codable {
    var testDate: Date? = nil
    let name: String
    let age: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case age
        case testDate
    }
}
```

Check [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types),

> ...Codable types can declare a special nested enumeration named CodingKeys that conforms to the CodingKey protocol. When this enumeration is present, its cases serve as the authoritative list of properties that **MUST** be included when instances of a codable type are encoded or decoded. The names of the enumeration cases should match the names you've given to the corresponding properties in your type.

Comment: or simply omit the coding keys enumeration